# Visual Studio - Can't close the IDE, create new solutions, or add references

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've built a new PC, and installed Visual Studio Community edition on it.

It worked great for a couple days, but around a week later, it has become unusable for the following reasons:

- I get 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' when trying to close the IDE! I have to kill devenv.exe from taskmgr.
- I regularly get 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: compositionService' when trying to add references. I simply can't add references
- I get 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' when trying to create a new solution.

I have a feeling that all are related to something and finding that something is my goal.

Any advice on how to remedy my IDE? I have no hope of being remotely productive at present!

Comment: Did you try running a repair of Visual Studio from installed programs?

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks.